# Updating jQuery version has broken ajax load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses jQuery 1.3.2.

On several of the pages there is a grid that lets you select multiple items, and then calls `.load` to load the details for the item.

```
this.$container.load(this.url, data, function() {
    // Show results
});
```

`data` containing an Array named `s` that contained the selected ids.

`s = [ "2", "1" ]`

Using jQuery 1.3.2, `data` would be posted as

```
s   2
s   1
```

Which was sent to

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(object[] s)
```

and everything worked great.

I tried to change the jQuery library to a more recent version (1.5.1) and now my controller doesn't receive the value of `s` because jQuery is posting `data` like so:

```
s[]   2
s[]   1
```

Do I need to assign an index in order for the controller to receive the value (`s[1], s[2]`)? Do I need to change the controller action's signature or the way the array is generated? Right now the javascript to generate data is simply

```
var s = new Array();
for (var id in this._selected) {
  // Some checks
  s.push(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it worked in 1.3.2, you should be able to revert to the old behaviour by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true`.  This is a change in jQuery 1.4, and this setting allows backwards compatibility.

See [the manual entry for `$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for more details.

Using your example data:

```
var data = {s: ["2", "1"]};

// jQuery 1.7
$.param(data); // "s%5B%5D=2&s%5B%5D=1"
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
$.param(data); // "s=2&s=1"

// jQuery 1.3.2
$.param(data); // "s=2&s=1"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but if I wanted to support the new way of doing things, is it possible to modify what I have or would I need to rely on the traditional setting?

Comment: @Brandon AFAIK (not being an MVC expert), this is "the way" to do this.